# PHPExcel - formatting a column as percent not applying

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to write an entire array to a sheet and a couple of my columns need to have the value in every cell displayed as a percent (ie with the percent sign).

My problem is that when I try to format column G as a percentage with this code:

```
$format_percent =  array('code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);
$objWorksheet->getStyle("G2:G".$rc)->applyFromArray($format_percent);
```

The resulting file has all cells in column G still with the "General" number format...not formated as a percent as I had hoped.
NOTE: the $rc variable is storing the row count

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.  I was trying to apply the formatting to the whole column at once.  That doesn't seem to work.  I thought it would because I CAN apply formatting like Bold to the text or and entire row at once.  However, when I did a test and applied the percent formatting to one cell, it worked fine.  So now I have just decided to loop over all of my cells in my column and apply the formatting one at a time.